# Statements vs Formulas

Tags: logic, terminology, first-order-logic

In *A Tour Through Mathematical Logic*, Wolf states that

> Every formula of a first-order language is a statement in the sense
>   of Section 1.2, but not conversely.

In Section 1.2, *Propositional Logic*, he mentions the following for statements:

> Let us use the word **statement** to
>   mean any declarative sentence (including mathematical ones such as
>   equations) that is true or false or could become true or false in the presence of additional information.

**Question:** When can a statement **not** be a formula?

Comment: "George Washington was the first President of the United States," is a statement that is not a formula.

Comment: Can't we view it as a nullary formula?

Comment: I don't see how it is part of a formal language in any way, but I'm no logician.

Comment: As far as I can tell, not having read the text, the author just means a formula is a formal thing (that either was or will be defined), while a statement is informal (which includes formal a special case).

Comment: @DerekElkins The text is [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=wlOS6XvzBIkC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false) and no, I don't think that is what he meant.

Comment: @JohnDouma Having read the context of the definition of "statement", I'm even more confident that is what Wolf means, though it is still somewhat unclear. What are you suggesting Wolf intends instead? One option would be the difference between a *closed* formula (often called a "sentence") and an open formula, but, as Henning Makholm suggests and was also my interpretation, the "additional information" seems to refer to an assignment to free variables (for the formal case). It's also unclear what non-mathematical statement we'd be including in the formal case.

Answer (score 2):

$P(x)$ is a formula, but not a statement.

Formulas can have free variables, and indeed $P(x)$ has a free (unquantified) variable $x$. Because it is not quantified, we cannot assign a truth-value to it, and so it is not a statement.

Indeed, note that I can quantifiy the $x$ either existentially or universally (or, if I had different quantifiers, differently yet). But, $\exists x \ P(x)$ is clearly a different statement than $\forall x \ P(x)$: I can easily come up with a domain and interpretation of $P(x)$ where $\exists x \ P(x)$ is true but $\forall x \ P(x)$ is false. So, I can indeed not assign a truth-value just to $P(x)$, so it is *not* a statement.

$P(x)$ *is* a formula though: it does follow the syntactical rules (the 'grammar' if you want) for expressions in FOL. I don;t have the text, but presumably the author lays out exactly those rules in defining formulas, and you can check for yourself that $P(x)$ does follow that definition. We sometimes therefore call formulas 'well-formed formulas' or wff's for short.

Something like $)xP)((,)$ is clearly *not* a formula ... that's just a string of symbols, but otherwise gibberish

Comment: Are you sure you're not confusing "statement" with "sentence"? (The two words have the same translation in Danish and probably other languages too). The definition the OP quotes allows for "... could become true or false in the presence of additional information" which seems to allow for free variables.

Comment: The author of the OP's text is saying the opposite. He says every formula is a statement and not conversely. I believe the OP is looking for a statement that is not a formula.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Exactly! That's what it means!

Comment: @Atom Aye, my bad. Yes, I clearly did not read the quotes correctly!  Well, .... then I don't really know what the author intended ...Will delete Answer soon ...